# In angular, how do you store state in the url without affecting routing?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I want to store filters that the user selects in the URL, but not affect routing. That way, the user can bookmark a page and later return and have the filters automatically populated.

Any good ideas on how to do this with angular?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the angular $stateProvider library and think about storing your user selections for the routes. You can then use `$state.go()` when your user wants to navigate to one of their bookmarks.